# Exactly what is patented

Tags: patent-services

In reference to the patent: [WO2010031854A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2010031854A1)

Hi. Can you please tell me exactly what is patented on these shopping bag? I have designed a better style, longer lasting and eco friendly...
Is the patent still valid, and in what countries?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: that is a patent *application*, not an actual patent.

The long answer is, that is a PCT (international) patent application, that must then be translated to one or more national patent offices (e.g. US, UK, etc) to actually mature into a patent. What you would need to do is check the relevant patent offices (based on your location / your market location) and see if the application was carried forward into any office and, if so, whether it actually matured into a patent, was abandoned/rejected, or is still in progress.